# serde: Deserialize `str` in Rust

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

I am working on an existing codebase in Rust, wherein I need to serialize/deserialize a struct with a `<'a, str>` type.

I am mentioning the minimal reproducible snippets here:

File: main.rs

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::cou::Cou;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TypePath<'a>(Vec<Cou<'a, str>>);
```

File: cou.rs

```
use std::{
    borrow::Borrow,
    sync::Arc,
};

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Cou<'a, T>
where
    T: ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a T),
    Upgraded(Arc<T::Owned>),
}
```

When I build the above, it gives an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/ast.rs:136:25
    |
136 | pub struct TypePath<'a>(Vec<Cou<'a, str>>);
    |                         ^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `str`
    |
    = help: the trait `Deserialize<'de>` is implemented for `&'a str`
note: required for `Cou<'a, str>` to implement `Deserialize<'_>`
   --> src/cou.rs:11:21
    |
11  | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
12  | pub enum Cou<'a, T>
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required for `Vec<Cou<'a, str>>` to implement `Deserialize<'_>`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Deserialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Now the output says that the trait is implemented for `&'a str` but I do not want to change TypePath in main.rs as it is used widely in the remainder of the codebase. Is it possible to define `Deserialize` for `str`?

Comment: The problem lies in the `Cou` enum. If you just `#[derive(Deserialize)]`, on a type that has a generic type `T`, then the implementation will have an implicit bound `T: Deserialize` despite the bound not always being useful in the actual implementation. This is one of these cases: `Cou` should either deserialize in `&T` or `T::Owned`, all of which implement `Deserialize` in this case, but not `T`, hence the error.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. How should I go about it then? Is there a `#[serde(..)]` macro that I can use here?

Comment: What about [`#[serde(borrow)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#borrow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cou` has the same structure as `Cow`, so you can almost copy-paste ser/de [implementations](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde/src/de/impls.rs#L1824-L1836) from serde.

```rust
use std::{sync::Arc};
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::ops::Deref;

use serde::{Deserializer, Deserialize, Serializer, Serialize};

pub enum Cou<'a, T>
  where
    T: ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
  Borrowed(&'a T),
  Upgraded(Arc<T::Owned>),
}


impl<B: ?Sized + ToOwned> Deref for Cou<'_, B>
  where
    B::Owned: Borrow<B>,
{
  type Target = B;

  fn deref(&self) -> &B {
    match *self {
      Cou::Borrowed(borrowed) => borrowed.borrow(),
      Cou::Upgraded(ref owned) => owned.deref().borrow(),
    }
  }
}


impl <'a, T: ?Sized> Serialize for Cou<'a, T> where T: Serialize + ToOwned {
  #[inline]
  fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
      S: Serializer,
  {
    (**self).serialize(serializer)
  }
}


impl<'de, 'a, T: ?Sized> Deserialize<'de> for Cou<'a, T>
  where
    T: ToOwned,
    T::Owned: Deserialize<'de>,
{
  #[inline]
  fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
      D: Deserializer<'de>,
  {
    T::Owned::deserialize(deserializer).map(Arc::new).map(Cou::Upgraded)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+std%3A%3A%7Bsync%3A%3AArc%7D%3B%0Ause+std%3A%3Aborrow%3A%3ABorrow%3B%0Ause+std%3A%3Aops%3A%3ADeref%3B%0A%0Ause+serde%3A%3A%7BDeserializer%2C+Deserialize%2C+Serializer%2C+Serialize%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F+main.rs%0A%23%5Bderive%28Serialize%2C+Deserialize%29%5D%0Apub+struct+TypePath%3C%27a%3E%28Vec%3CCou%3C%27a%2C+str%3E%3E%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F+cou.rs%0Apub+enum+Cou%3C%27a%2C+T%3E%0A++where%0A++++T%3A+ToOwned+%2B+%3FSized%2C%0A%7B%0A++Borrowed%28%26%27a+T%29%2C%0A++Upgraded%28Arc%3CT%3A%3AOwned%3E%29%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CB%3A+%3FSized+%2B+ToOwned%3E+Deref+for+Cou%3C%27_%2C+B%3E%0A++where%0A++++B%3A%3AOwned%3A+Borrow%3CB%3E%2C%0A%7B%0A++type+Target+%3D+B%3B%0A%0A++fn+deref%28%26self%29+-%3E+%26B+%7B%0A++++match+*self+%7B%0A++++++Cou%3A%3ABorrowed%28borrowed%29+%3D%3E+borrowed.borrow%28%29%2C%0A++++++Cou%3A%3AUpgraded%28ref+owned%29+%3D%3E+owned.deref%28%29.borrow%28%29%2C%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl+%3C%27a%2C+T%3A+%3FSized%3E+Serialize+for+Cou%3C%27a%2C+T%3E+where+T%3A+Serialize+%2B+ToOwned+%7B%0A++%23%5Binline%5D%0A++fn+serialize%3CS%3E%28%26self%2C+serializer%3A+S%29+-%3E+Result%3CS%3A%3AOk%2C+S%3A%3AError%3E%0A++++where%0A++++++S%3A+Serializer%2C%0A++%7B%0A++++%28**self%29.serialize%28serializer%29%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27de%2C+%27a%2C+T%3A+%3FSized%3E+Deserialize%3C%27de%3E+for+Cou%3C%27a%2C+T%3E%0A++where%0A++++T%3A+ToOwned%2C%0A++++T%3A%3AOwned%3A+Deserialize%3C%27de%3E%2C%0A%7B%0A++%23%5Binline%5D%0A++fn+deserialize%3CD%3E%28deserializer%3A+D%29+-%3E+Result%3CSelf%2C+D%3A%3AError%3E%0A++++where%0A++++++D%3A+Deserializer%3C%27de%3E%2C%0A++%7B%0A++++T%3A%3AOwned%3A%3Adeserialize%28deserializer%29.map%28Arc%3A%3Anew%29.map%28Cou%3A%3AUpgraded%29%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A)